# How to get multiple input from user VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, keypad

I want to read a 6-digit number from the user through the keypad which is connected to GPIO pins of FPGA board. this is part of my code:

```
signal kp_value :std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0);
signal kp_hit : std_logic ; 
type arr is array (23 downto 0) of std_logic_vector;    
signal num1 : arr; 
begin 
keypad_getInput: keypad port map(row, clk_50 , col , kp_hit, kp_value);


process(kp_hit)
begin 

if kp_hit ='1' then 

    num1 <= num1 & kp_value;
end if ;
end process;
seg_display: seven_segments port map(num1,sevenseg);
```

I want to keep getting number from the user until it reaches 24 bit and then displays it on six of 7-segments

I got errors, maybe the way of storing the values is wrong, could you please help me

Comment: 'I got errors' -- what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the bits you don't want to keep in `num`, I assume you want to shift left

```
num1 <= num1(19 downto 0) & kp_value;
```

Comment: could you please explain what this line does exactly? , I mean what value will be stored in num1(19 downto 0) ?

Comment: The value stored in num(19 downto 0)  stores the previous five key presses. The result of the assignment will push the latest key press into the lower 4 bits of num. Whilst keeping the previous five.

Comment: if I press key 1 it will put it in the lower 4 bit then for the second key, it will push the previous and store the new key in lower 4 bit? only from this statement ?

Comment: Yeah well sort of:
e.g. (if 8-bits i.e. in this case 'num' stores only two keys )
(1.) Previous state of 'num': 00001111
(2.) User presses key 1001
(3.) Next state of 'num' will be: 11111001
(4.) User presses key 0011
(5.) Next state of 'num' will be: 10010011